# In array returning the wrong result

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below array..

```
<?php $arrLayout = array(
    "section1" => array(
        "wComingEpisodes" => array(
            "title" => "Coming Episodes",
            "display" => ""
        )
    )); 
?>
```

Then I want to check if wComingEpisodes is in the array so..

```
<?php if (in_array( "wComingEpisodes" , $arrLayout )) {
echo "CHECKED";}
?>
```

However its returning nothing even though it is in the array. Do I need to do something different because of the multiple arrays or where is my mistake?

Comment: No; `"wComingEpisodes"` is not a value of the array `$arrLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array` tests for values, not keys. It also does not test nested values.

```
$arrLayout = array(
"section1" => array(
    "wComingEpisodes" => array(
        "title" => "Coming Episodes",
        "display" => ""
    )
)); 

echo array_key_exists( 
   "wComingEpisodes",
   // this is the array you're actually looking for
   $arrLayout['section1'] )?'exists':'does not exist';
```

Comment: Thanks this kinda works and I thought of a way to adapt it to work so will do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

you're getting the correct result according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

if you want to search an multidimensional array recursive, take a look at the user contributed notes, where you can find examples like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#97465), that show how to do a recursive search (which seems to be what you're looking for).

**EDIT:**
i just noticed you're trying to find out if a specific key exists: in this case, you'll have to use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) (like in_array, this also doesn't do a recursive search, so you'll have to do something like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#94601)).

Answer (score 0):

in array searches array values.

the string, "wComingEpisodes",  is the **key** of the value

you may want to try using [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: No. It's not even a key in the input array.

Answer (score 0):

In_array isn't recursive by nature so it will only compare the value you give it with the first level of array items of the array you give it.

Thankfully you're not the first with the problem so heres a function that should help you out. Taken from php.net in_array documentation

```
function in_arrayr($needle, $haystack) { 
        foreach ($haystack as $v) { 
                if ($needle == $v) return true; 
                elseif (is_array($v)) return in_arrayr($needle, $v); 
        } 
        return false; 
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#60696

Comment: the problem remains: in_array isn't the function realy Michael want's to use, he's looking for a key in the array - so the real solution would be to use a recursive version of array_key_exists ;)